# VSCODE - Disable highlighting and outlining in html tags and editor line

Tags: ide, visual-studio-code

These are some of the things I really find visually annoying in VSCODE, I was hoping someone could help me disable them.

**1.) Outlining <> in tags.**

[image: Check out the outlines in the tag.]

*I don't know about you, but I find this very annoying.*

**2.) Outline in the active line**

[image]

I ran through all the workspace settings and set to false all that might - or at least - in any way related to highlighting and outlining but no luck.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try this one `"editor.matchBrackets": false` in your Preferences - User/Workspace setting

[image: image here]

---

### Newer Visual Studio Code:

It's in Settings under `Editor: Match Brackets`

[image: U]

Answer (score 3):

The boxes really annoyed me, but I do like the indication.  I found an extension called Subtle Match Brackets.  It works perfect for me.  It changes to a subtle underline instead of the box.  Here's a link:

[Subtle Match Brackets](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rafamel.subtle-brackets)

Comment: That is an excellent extension.  Thank you for pointing it out.

Answer (score 2):

The active line outline can be disabled like this:

```json
"editor.renderLineHighlight": "none"
```

As for bracket highlighting, I couldn't find any setting for this either. It looks like there are at least three open issues related to this, so you might have to wait until those are resolved:

- [#18745](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/18745)
- [#16424](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/16424)
- [#3788](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/3788)

Personally, I find these indicators helpful. :)

Comment: Thank you. Please enlighten me as to how these are helpful?

Comment: Regarding matching brace highlighting - say you have nested function calls, it can be hard to tell where one call ends and another one starts, or if you got the number of closing braces right. This allows you to check that pretty easily. Of course, in your particular example it's not doing too much. :)

Answer (score -1):

See My Last 3 Setting's Press ctrl + , for VS Setting and Search [Check Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8hOb1.png)

Comment: Doesn't add anything new to the above answers... and you should embed the image here so it is always available in the future.