# Remove/change Matching Brackets Highlight in VSCode

Tags: vscode-extensions, visual-studio-code

The default matching brackets/parentheses highlight is too intrusive/bold for my liking and compare to Atom.
I can't find a way to disable it or change.
Is there CSS somewhere or an extension?
PS: This is for VSCode not Visual Studio.

Comment: I don't think that's possible right now. I listed some relevant issues here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/41815140/2631715

Comment: The duplicate I proposed is newer than this question, and asks to make bracket highlighting *more* visible, rather than less, but its [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43080788/95852) is the best answer to either question right now.

Comment: related: [Custom brace highlighting in Visual Studio Code](/q/39188214/11107541)

Answer (score 1):

> preferences -> settings and add this line in settings.json file

editor.matchBrackets": false