# Change bracket highlight weight in VS Code to be more visible

Tags: visual-studio-code, brackets

I'm just getting VS Code set up to use, one of the things I like to have is highlighting that's visible so I don't have to really look for it. I have the `editor.matchBrackets` setting set to `true`, so my brackets are highlighted when one is selected. However, the highlighting is so faint (very thin lines) that it's hard to see (I'm using the Dark+ theme, one of the default themes). Is there a way to affect the bracket highlighting, such as the color, line size, etc, so that it's easy to see?

Thanks.

Comment: 2020. IS NOW POSSIBLE!   https://stackoverflow.com/a/45640244/294884

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can't do that.

You should look for another Theme that fit your needs, or maybe *upvote* [this issue in VS Code repo](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/12402) which seems similar to your needs. This issue also suggest [install an extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=2gua.rainbow-brackets) that colorize brackets. It's not a solution, but might help.

Comment: IT CAN NOW BE DONE!  YAY !   https://stackoverflow.com/a/45640244/294884

Answer (score 2):

You can try this extension [Subtle Brackets](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rafamel.subtle-brackets#overview)  by modifying the following the default values in the .json settings of VS Code:

I changed it like this:

```
"subtleBrackets.bracketPairs": [
    "{}",
    "[]",
    "()",
    "<>"
],
"subtleBrackets.styles": {
    "global": {
        "color": "yellow",
        "borderWidth": "1px",
        "borderStyle": "none none solid none"
    }
}
```

Don't forget to set to "false" the value of .matchbrackets of VS Code.

```
"editor.matchBrackets": false
```

Answer (score 1):

you can add this setting to your settings.json file to apply lighter color brackets. You can just customize these colors of your interest. Bracket pair colorization should be enabled in settings

```
    "workbench.colorCustomizations": {
    "editorBracketHighlight.foreground1": "#ffffff",
    "editorBracketHighlight.foreground2": "#ffb534",
    "editorBracketHighlight.foreground3": "#d549ff",
    "editorBracketHighlight.foreground4": "#44ecff",
    "editorBracketHighlight.foreground5": "#9eff3e",
    "editorBracketHighlight.foreground6": "#2e74ff",
    "editorBracketHighlight.unexpectedBracket.foreground": "#db6165"
}
```

[image: Bracket pair custom colors]

If you want to have the same color for all nested brackets, you can disable "**independent color pool per bracket type**" in the settings.

Comment: Is there any way to make the bracket pairs use bold font? I'd prefer less saturation and to make different colors still readable using bold font would show more pixels with the same color which should help.