# Get rid of highlight boxes on HTML brackets

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm totally new to VS Code, coming from Atom.

When writing HTML elements, I am seeing the brackets highlighted with these boxes, and it is very distracting and clouds where my cursor is at times.

Any idea how to disable it?

(This screenshot is with all extensions disabled.)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/KUDuT.jpg

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [VSCODE - Disable highlighting and outlining in html tags and editor line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41797818/vscode-disable-highlighting-and-outlining-in-html-tags-and-editor-line)

Comment: It might, been trying, but not sure how to get to that json. Idiot, sorry. I don't see a path to it like it explained in the above.

Comment: To open `settings.json`, first open Command Palette via "Ctrl + Shift + P". Next, search for "Preferences: Open Settings (JSON)" and hit Enter.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. That fixed it. Thank you so much for your help and time, really appreciate it.